# How to write ArrayList<Object> to a csv file

Tags: java, csv, arraylist, opencsv

I have a `ArrayList<Metadata>` and i want to know if there is a Java API for working with CSV files which has a write method which accepts a ArrayList<> as parameter similar to LinqToCsv in .Net. As i know **OpenCSV** is available but the CsvWriter class doesn't accept a collection.
My Metadata Class is

```
public class Metadata{
    private String page;
    private String document;
    private String loan;
    private String type;
}
```

```
ArrayList<Metadata> record = new ArrayList<Metadata>();
```

once i populate the record, i want to write each row into a csv file.
Please suggest.

Comment: Why not. What about javacsv?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Surely there'll be a heap of APIs that will do this for you, but why not do it yourself for such a simple case? It will save you a dependency, which is a good thing for any project of any size.

Create a `toCsvRow()` method in `Metadata` that joins the strings separated by a comma.

```
public String toCsvRow() {
    return Stream.of(page, document, loan, type)
            .map(value -> value.replaceAll("\"", "\"\""))
            .map(value -> Stream.of("\"", ",").anyMatch(value::contains) ? "\"" + value + "\"" : value)
            .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
}
```

Collect the result of this method for every `Metadata` object separated by a new line.

```
String recordAsCsv = record.stream()
        .map(Metadata::toCsvRow)
        .collect(Collectors.joining(System.getProperty("line.separator")));
```

---

**EDIT**
Should you not be so fortunate as to have Java 8 and the Stream API at your disposal, this would be almost as simple using a traditional List.

```
public String toCsvRow() {
    String csvRow = "";
    for (String value : Arrays.asList(page, document, loan, type)) {
        String processed = value;
        if (value.contains("\"") || value.contains(",")) {
            processed = "\"" + value.replaceAll("\"", "\"\"") + "\"";
        }
        csvRow += "," + processed;
    }
    return csvRow.substring(1);
}
```

Comment: It creates a [stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#package.description) of an arbitrary number of objects of the same type. Streams are a new feature of Java 8.

Comment: ok, i am bound to Java 7, that's why it was not recognizing Stream.of(). is there any possible way to do this without stream i.e on Java 7.

Comment: Sure, mapping and collecting streams is just nicer. See updated answer – you should be able to do the last bit of putting each row on a separated line yourself.

Answer (score 1):

By using [CSVWriter](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/opencsv/CSVWriter.html), you could convert the `ArrayList` to an array, and pass that to the writer .

```
csvWriter.writeNext(record.toArray(new String[record.size()]));
```

Comment: this is a java.lang.ArrayStoreException

Answer (score 1):

If you have an ArrayList of Objects (Metadata in your case) you would use the BeanToCSV instead of the CSVWriter.

You can look at the [BeanToCSVTest in the opencsv source code](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/xref-test/au/com/bytecode/opencsv/bean/BeanToCsvTest.html) for examples of how to use it.

Comment: Typically, answers should stand on their own. Can you add a small code example class? The linked example is nearly 500 lines.

Comment: mmmmkay - How about the testWriteQuotes() test within the BeanToCSVTest which takes the testData arrayList and sends the result to the supplied Writer (for the test case it is a StringWriter so as I can test the result.   Sorry I do not mean to come off as snippy or sarcastic but I am ungodly busy and don't have time to write up examples.  Most of openCSV has tests that, while admitted as a whole are too much to be used as an example, can be looked at individually as examples.  In the future I will try and narrow down to specific tests that best answer the question.